# Installing Office 365 on WINE

Tags: wine, 19.10, playonlinux

I need to use Microsoft Office for a class I'm taking, and I can't use an alternative. I'm running WINE 4.5, Ubuntu 19.10, and PlayOnLinux 4.3.4, and I have access to the installer executable and installer disc image.

Each time I double-click the executable in either the image or the installer, it starts up and gets stuck on this screen for about a minute, and it crashes.[image: O365 Installer Loading Screen] I try to set this up in PlayOnLinux, and the same happens.

Comment: You wont get an answer here as this will require thorough knowledge of wine and office 365. WineHQ is a better place to ask about this.  As a reference see for instance https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=29676  and https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527&iTestingId=98964 "I need to use Microsoft Office for a class I'm taking, and I can't use an alternative" still no reason to use WINE. If you want a working office 365 use Windows. Virtualbox if you want to run it inside Linux. Less hassle and a far more superior experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use KVM instead of WINE to run windows on you linux machine. I find it better than Virtualbox

Comment: So, I'd need a full installation of Windows, right?

Comment: I can't find KVM. Is it `qemu-kvm`?

Comment: yesh but as a virtual machine. read this post to know more about it 
 https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Excellent! I'll try that out.