# Installing Microsoft Office 365 with wine

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I am trying to install MS Office 365 with wine but I got some errors:

I used the following:

```
    wine Setup64.exe
```

and I got the following:

```
 002c:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
 0040:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
 0047:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation"
 004a:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
```

After, I tried:

```
    sudo apt-get remove winbind && sudo apt-get install winbind
```

and I tried again:

```
    wine Setup64.exe
```

and I got the following:

```
 0047:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation"
 0049:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
```

Does anyone know how can I solve the remaining errors?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried to search in this forum? [Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1201247/906933) is a possible answer